# How to access specific calendar appointments in windowsphone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, calendar, appointment

I want to access to the calendar appointments in windows phone 8.
I'm using the below code.this code will retrieve all appointments:

```
    private void ButtonAppointments_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Appointments appts = new Appointments();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Appointments_SearchCompleted);

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime end = start.AddDays(7);
    int max = 20;

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    appts.SearchAsync(start, end, max, "Appointments Test #1");
}
```

but I want to get and show specific calendar.
For example I have three calendars in my outlook account: Mike's Calendar, Work's Calendar, Birthday Calendar. and I just want to show Mike's Calendar appointments in my app

In default calendar we can easily hide or show specific calendar but how can we do something like that in our own application????

Answer (score 1):

There is Windows Runtime API to get the different calendars.

```html
 AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);

            var appCalendars = await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentCalendarsAsync();
            foreach (var calendar in appCalendars)
            {
            }
```

The appCalendars is what you want.